# How to write the script for the check box in Selenium web driver by using Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

This is the button that I want to clicked. I want to check this button by writing automation scripts in selenium web driver by using Java.

The following is the code for the button.

```
<label class="toggle" style="font-size:13px">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-IsEFR" id="checkbox-IsEFR">
<i data-swchon-text="Yes" data-swchoff-text="No"></i>Is Enable for Rules
</label>
```

Please help me since I am new to automation scripts writing. I wrote the script for check box but it is not working. The following, I have attached the my scripts and the error generated.

```
@When("^clicks on enable for rules$")
    public void clicks_on_enable_for_rules() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("checkbox-IsEFR")).click();
    }
```

The error that I received.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with   Command duration
>   or timeout: 209 milliseconds   Build info: version: '2.53.0',
>   revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'   System info: host:
>   'DELL_I5', ip: '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'   Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver   Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]   Session ID:
>   03695ef8-bd24-49d6-b8a1-6687e3d0375c      at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)       at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)       at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>     at
>   mCollector.features.StepDefinitions_mCollector.clicks_on_enable_for_rules(StepDefinitions_mCollector.java:61)
>     at ✽.And clicks on enable for rules(C:/Users/Admin/workspace/MStudio
>   - eBilling/src/mCollector/features/mCollector.feature:12)   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with   Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'DELL_I5', ip: '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown      at .fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous546390466745105063webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous546390466745105063webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous546390466745105063webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous546390466745105063webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous546390466745105063webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: try driver.findElement(By.Id("checkbox-IsEFR")).click();

Comment: have you added an implicit wait in your test case like driver.manage().timeouts().implicitWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 1):

You can use explicit wait and [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for the checkbox to be visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("checkbox-IsEFR"))).click();
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be visible before clicking on it.

Comment: It also generates an error.   the error is as follows.  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: checkbox-IsEFR
      Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
      System info: host: 'DELL_I5', ip: '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'

Comment: @ChathurikaPrabodani Is there something covering the checkbox?

Comment: It doesn't clear to me. Can you describe what are u asking for. Actually the button is not combined with any part. It uses for either enable rules or not to enable rules as yes or no.

Comment: @ChathurikaPrabodani I'm asking if the checkbox is visible to you or is it hidden behind something else / you need to scroll to see it.

Comment: Setup -> Attributes -> then comes the form with this yes no check box.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is : "ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.."

There may be multiple reason of occurring this error but the strongest possibility is that:

The element is not loaded on the page and your code is trying to click it. To handle this you can put wait statement in your code. A global wait can be imposed by putting implicit wait `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` or you can try putting explicit wait statement before performing the click activity.

Try the solution and I think it'll resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can search by xpath in Selenium, using something like:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Is Enable for Rules')]").click()`